# Using python and BMesh, how do you select edges containing/touching a series of verts?

Tags: python, vertices, edges, bmesh

Using python and BMesh, how do you select edges containing/touching a certain vert? I'm using link_edges, but it has no select attribute, so the v.link_edges.select_set(True) is wrong.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
mesh = bpy.context.object.data  # Get selected object's mesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh) 

for v in bm.verts: 
    if len(v.link_edges) in (4,4): 
        v.link_edges.select_set(True)
        #select_set
        
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

Comment: The edges connected to a bmesh vert `v` are `v.link_edges`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using link_edges, but I haven't figured out how to select it. I've updated my answer to include my code.

Comment: Please review question. _"A certain vert"_ vs looping over all verts   If you know the vert `v` then `for e in bm.edges: e.select_set(e in v.link_edges)`  or as in above `if len(v.link_edges) == 4: for e in v.link_edges: e.select_set(True)`

Comment: I've revised the question. And that solved it. Now that it's answered, how should I mark it as answered?

Comment: @ZakNelson you can only mark as answered when the solutio is posted as a answer, as opposed to a comment. If batfinger does post an answer you should accept his. Otherwise we encourage you to write up your own question with a short explanation of the solution, and accept it